# How to render the black lines at the edges of an object?

Tags: blender-internal-render-engine

How to render an image like this with black lines ?

[image]

Image taken from the following faceboock page: https://www.facebook.com/glenyrenner/posts/1308258389303606?pnref=story

Comment: Rolled back to poster's original blender-render tag.  @Grimm freestyle may be one answer, but changing the tag clearly isn't poster's intention...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It is called **Freestyle Line style**

Add a base color and in the Render -> Freestyle (tick mark)

[image]

If you want to change the color of the stroke (line)
Under Render Layer -> Freestyle Line style -> color -> Base color (change the color from black to any color)

[image]

Hit F12 to render after finishing the render wait a second to complete the Freestyle Line style render and you can see a outline of the color.

[image]

Comment: Thank you. This is what I was looking. But I don't know the name of that feature (y)